# Java - Issue in a Recursive Backtracking Maze

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, maze

After reading [this](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2010/12/27/maze-generation-recursive-backtracking) blog post, I decided to use it to create a maze in Java to use the A* algorithm to solve. The maze generation works well. I've modified the code slightly to work with Java & my purposes.

Unfortunately, I didn't think about it when I started, but the example prints it as ASCII. I would like to have it be a two dimensional array with one's and zero's to use for the path finding.

Currently, it prints the characters, as an example if width & height = 10, it would look something like this:

```
___________________
| |  _  |_    |_  |
| | |  _|  _| |   |
|___| |_  | | | | |
|  ___|  _| |___| |
|_  |_  |  _|  ___|
| |_____|  ___|   |
|      _| |  ___| |
| | |_|  _| | |  _|
|_|_________|_____|
```

I also have it draw the maze to a GUI. This one looks like this (it is rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise so that (1, 1) is in the bottom left):

[image: 10x10 Maze]

I currently have the ASCII maze being added to a two dimensional String array. the possible values of the strings in the array are:

```
" ",
"_",
"  ",
" _",
" |",
"_ ",
"__",
"_|",
```

would there be a way to loop through the array containing the maze, and assign a 1 or 0 based on what the next character is in the ASCII maze? if so, how would you account for the additional space above the horizontal lines, that are not going to be recognized as an open space?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Did you read the bottom paragraph, or any of it for that matter? I’m not sure that my question required code to be posted. I️ can post how I️ currently have it, but that doesn’t really seem like it’s going add to the question of “How can I️ account for the space above the horizontal lines that will be added as a 1, but needs to have the one and the space above it.”

Comment: So you have current code that you want to change, and you're asking "would there be a way to loop through the array containing the maze, and assign a 1 or 0 based on what the next character is in the ASCII maze?". It's hard to figure out what you currently have, on which your question is based, without seeing that code.

Answer (score 1):

Just double the height internally, then you can convert

- '_' to '▄' (0 above 1)
- '|' to '█' (1 above 1)
- ' ' to ' ' (0 above 0)